# Handler crashes when rendering

Tags: python

Blender is crashing during rendering with this handler.
Can someone tell me why? Maybe context is a problem. But how
do I now what else to use in the handler? I'm confused about
this task. It works absolutely fine in the viewport...

```
import bpy, bmesh

def my_handler(scene, depsgraph):
    frame = scene.frame_current
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new('MyCube')
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bmesh.ops.create_cube(
            bm,
            size=5,
            )
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    bm.free()
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(me.name,me)
    col_objs = bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects
    col_objs.link(obj)
    
    obj.location[2] = frame
    print(col_objs)
    
    if len(col_objs) > 4:
        bpy.data.objects.remove(col_objs[0],do_unlink=True)
        
    

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it with the blender API Doc.

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html

Just locked the interface while rendering and everything worked perfectly.

```
bpy.context.scene.render.use_lock_interface = True
```

Comment: Please also note the arguments passed to the handlers. They are `(scene, depsgraph)` not `(self, context)` it is only that there is both a `context.scene` and a `depsgraph.scene` that the handler in question works as expected.

Comment: Thank you batFINGER, I found already some posts about this depsgraph, but couldn't understand what that is doing. I'm also confused because everything worked only with "self". No context, no scene, just self and it worked. There is some stuff about the blender API I can't understand at the moment. Please let me now if there is some good place to learn about it.